# How to fix this memory leaks?

Tags: android, performance, memory-leaks, leakcanary

[image]

how i can fix this Memory Leaks i am using this code to work with handler.

```
public static Handler handlerKillInfoBar = new MyHandler();
if (handlerKillInfoBar != null) {
        handlerKillInfoBar.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
handlerKillInfoBar.postDelayed(() -> {
         // doing some work here. when user navigate between activites then memory leaks happend and show attached information.    

        }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `BaseActivity` class has a `timerHearBeatApiCall` static field which is a LambdaObserver, and `VodActivity` subscribes to it. `VodActivity` should unsubscribe when it receives its `onDestroy()` callback.

Also, you should upgrade to LeakCanary 2.x

Comment: Thanks for replying back. I tried but still, I am getting the same issue. 
Any idea,  how I can free memory for base activity while changing activity to other activity. 
also, leak canary showing injected object are the reason for memory leaks. how to release memory for dagger2 injected objects.